# Criar BD via PHP => Access Denied!

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

Estou tentando criar um BD via script PHP, mas está retornando ACCESS DENIED.

```
<?php
   $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbuser = 'usuario_root';
   $dbpass = 'senha_root';

   $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
   if($conn->connect_error )
   {
     die('Could not connect: %s' . $conn->connect_error);
   }
   echo "Connected successfully\n\n";


   $sql = "CREATE DATABASE novobd";

   if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){

     echo "Created the database\n";

   }

   else {
     echo "Failed to create the database: ".$conn->error;
   }

   //Close the database
   $conn->close();
 ?>
```

**ERRO:**

> Connected successfully Failed to create the database: Access denied
>   for user 'usuario_root'@'localhost' to database 'novobd'

Seria alguma configuração no CPanel, ou no PHP.ini?

Answer (score 1):

Você tem como compartilhar um print da tela de erro?

Normalmente esse erro ocorre nas situações:

1. Você utilizou as credenciais incorretas de acesso ao banco de dados (host, usuario e/ou senha).
2. Ou por algum motivo que apenas seu host saberia responder você não tem permissões de está acessando / utilizando o banco de dados.
3. O usuário que você está tentando conectar não tem essas persmissões.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o erro. O usuário é o root.

Comment: Mas você conseguiu conectar?

Comment: Sim, conectar consegue. Só não consigo criar o BD.

Comment: Então no seu caso é problema de permissões, tente contactar o DBA ou responsável do seu host e verificar se o usuário que você está tentando conectar tem permissões de se conectar à base de dados.

Comment: O usuário term acesso sim, é o usuário root, o qual acesso CPanel, etc.
Nem sei mais o que pode ser =/